# grep pipe with sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

This is my bash command

```
grep -rl "System.out.print" Project1/ | 
    xargs -I{} grep -H -n "System.out.print" {} |
    cut -f-2 -d: |
    sed "s/\(.*\):\(.*\)/filename is \1 and line number is \2/
```

What I'm trying to do here is,I'm trying to iterate through sub folders and check what files contains "System.out.print" (using grep)
using 2nd grep trying to get file names and line numbers
using sed command I display those to console.
from here I want to remove "System.out.print" with "XXXXX" how I can pipe sed command to this?
pls help me
thanxx

Comment: why don't you simply use `grep -rn "System.out.print" Project1/` instead of that monster pipe?

Comment: the thing is I want to replace "System.out.print" with "XXXXX",Can you tell me better way to do this,I'm bit new to this

Comment: repeating yourself verbatim does not make your question clearer

Comment: let me tell this way,there lot of files(directory structure) contains "word1" I want to replace that word with "word2" so could you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: 1. i already did tell you in my answer. 2. what does that have to do with the script you pasted?

Answer (score 11):

GNU sed has an option to change files in place:

```
find Project1/ -type f | xargs sed -i 's/System\.out\.print/XXXXX/g'
```

Btw, your script could be written as:

```
grep -rsn 'root' /etc/ |
    awk -F: '{ print "filename is", $1, "and line number is", $2 }'
```

Comment: or maybe i have completely misunderstood your question… could you please try to give a clearer description of what you want?

Comment: Is this working in recursive way??I want to access sub folders also

Comment: Actually this is not my home work I have project with lot of S.O.P so I want to remove  those.I tried various ways,but I couldn't find a way to do this.I want to know how I can pipe grep with sed,I'm asking a bit help from you guys

Comment: @hop I'd go with find's `-exec` since only one command is needed (sed) to be run with the filename as an argument.

Comment: `find` is recursive unless you specify additional options (see `man find`).

Comment: @plundra: sure, but i wanted to avoid introducing too many new concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just building on hop's answer, which I found to be more useful than `find -exec`.  I had **search_text** dispersed all over my computer, in logs, config files and so on, but I didn't want to search (or especially change) anything in /dev, /sys, /proc, and so on.  One note, read man xargs; it doesn't like file names with spaces.

```
grep -HriIl --exclude-dir=dev --exclude-dir=proc --exclude-dir=sys search_text / | xargs sed -i 's/search_text/replace_text/g'
```

Comment: `grep | xargs` is nice too.
`find -print0` | xargx -0` is a good way to handle spaces in filenames.